# C# HTTPWebRequest.GetResponse() strips out query string

Tags: c#, web-scraping, query-string, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm almost certain that I'm just misunderstanding how query strings should be passed in using C# HTTPWebRequest/Response, but I can't figure out why when I call `(HTTPwebResponse)request.GetResponse();` it strips out the query portion and only gives the resulting HTML of the base URL. What am I doing wrong? Note that I generalized the URL for simplicity but kept the same query string just in case the structure of that is the problem.

```cs
string urlQueryString = "https://baseUrl.com/folder1/folder2?status_filter_mode=approved";
var targetUri = Uri.EscapeUriString(urlQueryString);

request = HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
request.Method = "GET";
//set the cookie in the request header
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookiedata);

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        htmlResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
response.Close();
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the url for this request. Remove this
var targetUri = Uri.EscapeUriString(urlQueryString);

Comment: A response does not have a query string. It sounds like you are saying the service you are calling is returning results as if the query string was not even set? Is that right? If so then either your filter is somehow wrong of there's an issue with the service implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually threw this in right before posting this because I had tried it without escaping the url with no avail. I'll remove it though since it didn't help.

Comment: @Crowcoder that is correct it only returns the results from the base url without the query string. I copy and pasted the filter from the browser, unsure if that would cause problems though. As far as the service implementation, are you suggesting that the website that i am trying to scrape is possibly stripping it out on the request? Or something else?

Comment: If that url works in the browser then take a closer look at the html you are getting back. It may be an error response of some kind. Maybe your cookie is not set right, maybe your user agent string is rejected, etc.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'll check that out, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Quick update that may or may not be helpful. But I added the following line below the line where I set the response and it correctly redirected to the filtered page. So maybe the response is getting set correctly and the stream is taking something out?

Response.Redirect(response.ResponseUri.ToString());